# Background color only appears on half of screen in landscape mode

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I am building a sample login page. Everything is working fine but when I run the project on the device in landscape mode, the background color is covering only half part of the screen. I searched Google. I found 1 matching answer but it's not working.

Here is my code for background color:

```
let topColor = UIColor(red: 254/255.0, green: 81/255.0, blue: 150/255.0, alpha: 1)
let bottomColor = UIColor(red: 247/255.0, green: 112/255.0, blue: 98/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
let gradientColors: [CGColor] =  [topColor.cgColor, bottomColor.cgColor]
let gradientLocations: [Float] = [0.0, 1.0]
let gradientLayer: CAGradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
gradientLayer.colors = gradientColors
gradientLayer.locations = gradientLocations as [NSNumber]
gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

And the result I'm getting:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is a common mistake. The `frame` of the gradientLayer does not get updated when the view is laid out for the landscape mode. You have to do it manually.

**SOLUTION**

Be sure that you create `gradientLayer` and insert it as sublayer only once (e.g., in `viewDidLoad`). Keep `gradientLayer` as a instance property of the `viewController` so that you have access to it.

Then override `layoutSubviews` and there refresh the frame of the `gradientLayer`:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    // at this self.view has updated its layout, so now you can update gradientLayer's frame
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
}
```